# FiveM Automatic Restart Script

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a restart script for my FiveM server and this is the code that I have so far:

```
@echo off
:: Config

TITLE CFR FIVEM SERVER
set reboot1 = 00
set reboot2 = 06
set reboot3 = 12
set reboot4 = 18 

:: Logic

: start
echo [%time%] - Server Started!
start D:\Server\run.bat +exec server.cfg  
goto loop

: restart
echo [%time%] - Server Reboot
taskkill /f /im FXServer.exe >nul
timeout /t 10 >null
goto start

: loop
timeout /t 5 >null
set tps = %TIME:~-0,2%
echo %tps%
if %tps%==%reboot1% goto restart

if %tps%==%reboot2% goto restart

if %tps%==%reboot3% goto restart

if %tps%==%reboot4% goto restart
```

I want it to have scheduled restarts every 6 hours. For Example 00:00, 06:00, 12:00, and 18:00

When I run it (having echo on), the echo and if statement variables in the loop appear empty in the console. For example the console thinks its: `if == goto restart`

Could anyone help me with this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: you  are assigning variables named like `tps` + _space_, unless you remove the spaces around the equal-to signs...

Comment: There's no need for using a negative zero here, `%TIME:~-0,2%`, just `%TIME:~0,2%` should do it, or even `%TIME:~,2%`. Additionally unless you want a file named `null` in your current working directory, you should change both your `timeout` commands to redirect to the `NUL` device, as you have already done correctly with your `taskkill` command. It also doesn't make sense to start the server, regardless of what the hour is, because if the time falls within one of your restart times, you'll be rebooting it around 5 seconds later. Also, please use `Rem` for remarks, not malformed labels, `::`.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact I cannot see a reason not to just run `D:\Server\run.bat` from the task scheduler at the times you require and with `+exec server.cfg` as its arguments, I would probably offer this enhancement to what you appear to be trying to do.

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
Title CFR FIVEM SERVER
Call :CheckIfRunning
If ErrorLevel 1 (Echo [%TIME%] Starting Server
    GoTo StartServer)

:GetHourMatch
Set "#=1" & For /F "Tokens=2Delims=: " %%G In (
    '"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe \: . /NJH /L|%__AppDir__%find.exe " 123""'
) Do Set /A "#=(1%%G%%25)%%6"
If %#% Neq 0 GoTo :EOF

:KillServer
%__APPDIR__%taskkill.exe /F /Im FXServer.exe >NUL

:Loop
If %#% Equ 11 (Echo [%TIME%] - Reboot Error
    GoTo :EOF)
%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak >NUL
Call :CheckIfRunning
If ErrorLevel 1 (Echo [%TIME%] - Server Reboot
    GoTo StartServer)
Set /A #+=1
GoTo Loop

:StartServer
Start D:\Server\run.bat +exec server.cfg
GoTo :EOF

:CheckIfRunning
%__APPDIR__%tasklist.exe /Fi "ImageName Eq FXServer.exe"^
 /Fi "Status Eq Running" /Fo CSV /NH^
 | %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /I "\"FXServer.exe\"">NUL && (
    Exit /B 0) || Exit /B 1
```

The idea of the script is that upon starting, it checks if `FXServer.exe` is running, if it isn't it just runs `D:\Server\run.bat +exec server.cfg` to start it, then closes. If it is running, it checks if the hour, `HH`, is either `00`, `06`, `12` or `18`, if it isn't it closes the script.

At this point if the script is still running, it means that `FXServer.exe` is running and the hour is either `00`, `06`, `12` or `18`, so it kills tries to kill `FXServer.exe`. It then enters a loop to make checks that `FXServer.exe` is not running, in order to start it again, *(you cannot start it until it has stopped)*. It will check that up to `10` times with `3` second intervals, to ensure that it is given sufficient time to be killed cleanly. As soon as the check indicates that it is not running, `D:\Server\run.bat +exec server.cfg` is run and the script closes. If after `10` checks, *(around `30` seconds)*, it indicates that `FXServer.exe` is still running, an error message is printed and the script closes.